# Multiple scripts but bottom script is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two scripts. One is a validation script the other is to enlarge some images on hover. (I know I can use CSS to do it, I'm experimenting). I cannot figure out why the bottom script will not work. Its probably something obvious that I am not seeing. Please help.

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(function(){
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("form[name='registration']").validate({
    // Specify validation rules
    rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      firstname: "required",
      lastname: "required",
      email:
       {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },

      }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      firstname: "Please enter your first name",
      lastname: "Please enter your last name",
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
    // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
    // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }

document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseover", imageEnlarge);
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseout", imageReset);  




 function imageEnlarge() {
 document.getElementById('1').style.height="100%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.width="100%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.position='absolute';
 }
 function imageReset() {

 document.getElementById('1').style.height="80%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.width="80%";
 document.getElementById('1').style.position='absolute';
 }


});
});
```

Comment: Neither imageEnlarge, nor imageReset are ever called

Comment: How do I call them? This has been an overview class I'm taking and we blazed through javascript.

Comment: You need to call function , you have declared it but never called it
, add  imageEnlarge(); to your DOM Ready function

Comment: I did or I thought I had and it is still not working. Can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the call to the imageEnlarge() and imageReset() functions on to the mouseover and mouseout events of the image to affect.

Using the element id you have, it would be this:

```
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseover", imageEnlarge);
document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseout", imageReset);
```

You also have some errors in your code, so I've updated it accordingly. See the comments with marked with two asterisks ** :

```
$(function () {
    // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
    // It has the name attribute "registration"
    $("form[name='registration']").validate({
        // Specify validation rules
        rules: {
            // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
            // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
            // on the right side
            firstname: "required",
            lastname: "required",
            email:
                {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },    
            // ** Removed closing brace **
        },
        // Specify validation error messages
        messages: {
            firstname: "Please enter your first name",
            lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
        },
        // Make sure the form is submitted to the destination defined
        // in the "action" attribute of the form when valid
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

    // ** Moved this code out from the validate function - otherwise **
    // ** it will not be run until the validation function is called. **

    document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseover", imageEnlarge);
    document.getElementById("1").addEventListener("mouseout", imageReset);

    function imageEnlarge() {
        document.getElementById('1').style.height = "100%";
        document.getElementById('1').style.width = "100%";
        document.getElementById('1').style.position = 'absolute';
    }

    function imageReset() {

        document.getElementById('1').style.height = "80%";
        document.getElementById('1').style.width = "80%";
        document.getElementById('1').style.position = 'absolute';
    }
});
```

Comment: I added them to my calls and saved in my environment and still nothing.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to show me where you placed the above code please?

Comment: I wasn't closing off the scripts to ensure they would fire off?

Comment: It's not about closing off any script, the code itself was invalid. The extra closing brace after the 'rules' property would signify the end of the 'rules' definition, but you would then need a comma afterwards to define the next property 'messages' (as the code already does). The extra brace made the code invalid. The 'enlarge' and 'reset' functions, as well as the event handlers, should be declared when the page loads - not when the 'validate' function is called. So your 'mouseover' event wouldn't be declared until you submitted the form and the 'validate' function was called.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would there be any reason this still wouldn't work? My validation is working but when I hover over the images they still don't do anything. My site is saying there are some errors but I don't understand them.

Comment: The code above works as is. I'll need to see the rest of your code to see if there are any other issues stopping the code working. Can you add the HTML and any other javascript you may have loaded on the page?

Comment: Seeing as this question has been answered. I am going to start a new questions.

Comment: No problem, please mark as answered for this one, I'll take a look at your new one.